# Carrying a heavy pile of books, he caught his foot on a step. (meaning of idiomatic expression: catch one's foot on a step)

Tags: meaning, idiomatic-language

> Carrying a heavy pile of books, he caught his foot on a step.

Analysis: He may've carried a heavy pile of books using both of his hands.

Q: How could he catch his foot without his hands? So 'caught' here means he didn't use his hands.

Then, there could be some other things that caught his foot—a step or his the other foot(left or right) or he himself as an owner of his body who can control the movement of each part of his body.

But the subject of 'caught' is "he", so 'a step' is out and, in, he himself, either left or right foot.

What does the expression of "catch one's feet on a step" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"To catch" can also mean "to accidentally trap".

Say you are going upstairs, and you don't raise your foot high enough to completely clear the riser, and you accidentally trip over the riser instead of placing your foot firmly on the next step.

That is "catching your foot on a step".

Similar usage is when you "catch a finger in the door" -- you accidentally close the door when your fingers are in the way, and they end up between the door and the jamb.

Answer (score 1):

A simple answer is, "catch his foot on a step" means to "trip over" the step.

I've probably introduced yet another idiom.

However hands are absolutely not involved.

Catch, in this sentence, implies involuntary interrupted movement, not something you do with your hands, which is a completely different (if more usual) usage.